# What do the values mu and s represent in the RBF kernel in this code?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, statistics, octave

I was given this code to form a population value from a number of neurons in an NN with this description:

To produce a population code for a value "a" using a set of neurons with
preferred inputs in the range [0:0.1:1] and Gaussian receptive fields
with standard deviation 0.15, you would do the following:

code_for_a=code(a,[0:0.1:1],0.15)

The decode function calculates the value represented by a population
code, e.g.

a=decode(code_for_a,[0:0.1:1])

But I do not understand what the values for the parameters mu and s represent in the code function. Can anyone give me an example? I think that would help me get a better understanding.

Code function:

```matlab
function z=code(mu,s,sigma)
%create a population code, z, for an input variable with value mu using neurons
%with Gaussian RFs centred at the preferred values defined by s and with
%standard deviation sigma.

if isnan(mu)
  z=zeros(1,length(s),'single');
else
  sigma=max(1e-6,sigma); %prevent sigma being too small
  z=exp(-(0.5/sigma.^2).*(mu-s).^2);
end
```

decode function:

```matlab
function [mu]=decode(z,s)
%decodes a population code, z, that has been encoded using a population of
%neurons with preferred values defined by s
mu=sum(z.*s)./sum(z);
```

Comment: What parameters are used to define a gaussian distribution?

Comment: sigma and mu, but in this context the parameter mu doesn't seem like the mean of the values of the neurons and that's why I'm asking for an example to help me understand.